# Page in Ionic is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a ionic 3 project and the file app.module.ts is like :

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    AdminPage,
    ActuDetailPage,
],...
```

When I deploy as dev on my android device, no problem, but when I deploy with --prod --release parameter, I have the following error message :

```
Type ActuDetailPage in /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.ts is part of the 
        declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/app/app.module.ts and 
        ActuDetailPageModule in /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.module.ts! 
        Please consider moving ActuDetailPage in 
        /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.ts to a higher module that imports 
        AppModule in /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/app/app.module.ts and ActuDetailPageModule in 
        /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.module.ts. You can also create a new 
        NgModule that exports and includes ActuDetailPage in 
        /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.ts then import that NgModule in 
        AppModule in /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/app/app.module.ts and ActuDetailPageModule in 
        /Users/poste5hookipa/sites/frApp4/src/pages/actu-detail/actu-detail.module.ts.
```

SO that I have to un comment like this :

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    /* AdminPage,
    ActuDetailPage,*/
```

With the latter I can deploy as prod, but using this same comment, deploying in dev generate an error.
How to organize the code to be compliant either as dev and prod? thanks

Comment: Can you make sure that your `ActuDetailPage` isn't, in fact, declared by two module ? If so, can you rename one of the two ?

Comment: it's declared in actu-detail.module.ts also,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **Shared Module**, declare the Page component in it and also add it in the exports array

And then import  Shared Module in the 2 modules you mentioned.

Like this:

**SharedModule :**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminPage,
    ActuDetailPage
  ],
 exports: [
    AdminPage,
    ActuDetailPage
 ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**Module1 and Module2 :**

```
 @NgModule({
      imports: [
        SharedModule, 
        ...
      ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got rid of the problem, the message says simply that the module is not part of any module, and place the actu-detail.ts in a module file. actu-detail.ts was indeed declared in ActuDetailPageModule, but ActuDetailPageModule was not imported in AppModule.

In the app.module.ts, in the @NgModule, the imports property is an array of modules, I simply added the AdminPageModule, ActuDetailPageModule to solve the problem.

```
@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
HomePage,
],
imports: [
AdminPageModule,
ActuDetailPageModule,
....],
```